# What is the probability that there is an error in both blocks?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A computer program consists of two blocks written independently by two different programmers.   The  first  block  has  an  error  with  probability  $0.2$,  the  second  block  has  an  error  with probability $0.3$.  If the program returns an error, what is the probability that there is an error in both blocks?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I denoted with A the event that I have an error in the first block and with B in the second one. So P(A)=0.2 and P(B)=0.3. Due to the fact that they are independent I'd say that the probability must be P(A and B), but I dont't think that's ok.

Comment: Furthermore, the problem can't be solved as stated.  We need information regarding the independence of the two blocks. Perhaps an error in block $1$ always causes an error in block $2$, perhaps the two blocks produce errors independently.  There's no way to guess at that.

Comment: @lulu "*written independently*"

Comment: They are independent.

Comment: @Amy_Farrah_Fowler Do not confuse P(A and B) with P(A and B *given that A or B*).  You have ignored the phrase "*if the program returns an error...*"

Comment: @JMoravitz  The fact that they were written independently really doesn't say anything about the errors they produce.  many numerical methods fail under similar circumstance, for example.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I didn't take into consideration the if...

Comment: So,it will be P(A and B)/P(A or B)?

Comment: In order to attack this problem, you must first stretch your intuition around
two concepts (1) Bayes Theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem.
(2) Inclusion-Exclusion : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle.
As already commented by saulspatz, mathSE reviewers are not allowed to hand you an answer
until you first edit your query to show work, regardless of whether your
work solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this figure:

[image]

So your answer is $\frac{0.06}{.2 + .3 - .06}$ which is simply the intersection over the union, as shown by JMoravitz.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. @JMoravitz has provided correct formula

Comment: Check again....

Comment: I thought you answered 0.06. Thank  you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$\Pr(X\mid Y) = \dfrac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$

and in particular letting $X=A\cap B$ and $Y= A\cup B$ and noting that $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ you have

$$\Pr(A\cap B\mid A\cup B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cup B)}$$

Comment: As formulas provided by JMoravitz in the above answer, the correct value is 0.1364